# Writing Pandas Data Frame live to Excel file (.XLSX) using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I have to see the excel file getting updated live with my pandas data frame that is being read from a CSV file.

Below is my CSV file. And I am reading the CSV with the help of pandas, but I am not sure how to put this into an Excel file.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use another modules or it is mandatory to use xlwings?

Comment: @A.Wolf  No, It's not mandatory. Please suggest some other module.

Comment: It's enough that you write the data on the file? I mean, you have to close the file to see modifications. I don't think you can modify it dynamically, without closing it.

Comment: @A.Wolf I don't want to close my file. File should be remained open and I should be able to see the data getting updated.

Comment: simple approach is use pandas method `DF.to_excel("Output_file.xlsx")`

Comment: Are you doing this in windows?

Comment: @JohanL yes sir ! I have also went through the win32 library but I'm not still getting a proper way to insert data ..every example w.r.t to win32 is having range mentioned where the data is needed to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879391/editing-an-open-document-with-python), which says that Excel works on a copy of the document.

To write a dataframe to Excel file you can use the pandas `to_excel()` method like this:

```
your_dataframe.to_excel(output.xlsx')
```

A good module to work with Excel with more details is xlwt. You can see [this tutorial](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/6932/xlwt.Workbook) which explains how to use it with many examples.

Comment: I am already using openpyxl for putting data into Excel file and I am also using this "df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs, header=True)" to put data frame into excel file , but the problem is that when I open the Excel file I can't see the data getting updated live.

Comment: Ok :) I added the first link that I think could help you, I don't think you can di this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not too concerned with speed, as the updates are to happen realtime and visible to the user. The way I can think of to achieve this, is to use the win32 apis for com objects, available in Python on Windows, through the `win32com` package. To comunicate with other objects, we typically want the `win32com.client` package.

Using this, it is rather straight forward to write to an open excel book:

```
import win32com.client as win32

filename = "book.xlsx"

# Get a handle to excel:
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
# Find open workbook with "filename" (which is the base name only)
wb = excel.Workbooks(filename)
# Set active sheet
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

# We can access a single cell with "Cells":
ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "A1"
# Or multiple cells with a "Range" (note the strange tuple format of values)
ws.Range("C1:C3").Value =[("C1",), ("C2",), ("C3",)]
```

This example should be rather straight forward to turn into something that you can use to write your `pandas`data into excel. However it will require you to "manually" loop over your different cells and write them to the excel document.